# Drag and Drop objects on scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

Please tell me how to do something similar in Unity for 3D scene (left menu)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJr8u.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is: once the object is clicked and starting to be dragged, get the item's name. Then when the mouse is released send a raycast out in the scene (screenpointtoray), and lastly instantiate the object that was dragged at the raycast's .point value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Ray. This is how I am doing it on my current project:

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit rayHit;
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out rayHit))
{
    // ... instantiate object here
    newObject.transform.position = rayHit.point;
}
```

That will instantiate an object at the point where the ray collides with an object. All of my meshes have the origin at the bottom, so my new objects will appear exactly on top of whichever object is under the mouse.